# How send eigen a matrix to GLSL?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glsl, eigen

How send "Eigen matrix" to GLSL?
For example this:

```
// Set up the model and projection matrix
Eigen::Matrix<GLfloat,4,4> projection_matrix;

projection_matrix = frustum(-1.0f, 1.0f, -aspect, aspect, 1.0f, 500.0f);
glUniformMatrix4fv(render_projection_matrix_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &projection_matrix.data()[0]);
```

I looked this `way(matrix.date()[0])` for uBLAS, but Eigen isn't uBLAS. How I can do this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `eigen/demos/opengl` directory.

Answer (score 10):

Simply call the .data() function:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(render_projection_matrix_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, projection_matrix.data());
```

You might also be interested by the `<unsupported/Eigen/OpenGLSupport>` module which allows you to write:

```
glUniform(render_projection_matrix_loc, projection_matrix);
```

while taking care of the dimensions, scalar type, storage layout, etc. For instance, it also works with expressions:

```
glUniform(render_projection_matrix_loc, 2*projection_matrix.tranpose());
```